# LINQ: Filter by value in sub list

Tags: c#, linq

I have obtained a list like this:

```
int[] listOfUserIds = new int[]{1,2,5};

var groups = db.some_table.Where(x => x.isOpen == true)
                        .Select(t => new Models.XModel() {
                            Id = t.Id,
                            Name = t.name,
                            Users = t.Users.Where(x => x.Age > 25).Select(user => new Models.UsersModel()
                            {
                                Name = user.Name,
                                UserId = user.UserId
                            })
                        });
```

Now from this `groups` list I would like to get the records where there is atleast one `user` whose `UserId` is within `listOfUserIds`.

How to achieve this easily without for loop?

Comment: Without `for` loop this is impossible. LINQ include `for` loops

Comment: I meant without explicitly using for loop and if there is a higher abstraction available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 1 more condition to your `Where` clause:

```
x.Users.Any(user => listOfUserIds.Contains(user.UserId))
```

Your code:

```
var groups = db.some_table.Where(x => x.isOpen == true && x.Users.Any(user => listOfUserIds.Contains(user.UserId)))
                        .Select(t => new Models.SomeModel() {
                            Id = t.Id,
                            Name = t.name,
                            Users = t.Users.Where(x => x.Age > 25).Select(user => new Models.UsersModel()
                            {
                                Name = user.Name,
                                UserId = user.UserId
                            })
                        });
```

To improve performance, you can build a `HashSet<int>`:

```
int[] listOfUserIds = new int[]{1,2,5};
HashSet<int> hash = new HashSet<int>(listOfUserIds);

var groups = db.some_table.Where(x => x.isOpen == true && x.Users.Any(user => hash.Contains(user.UserId)))
                            .Select(t => new Models.SomeModel() {
                                Id = t.Id,
                                Name = t.name,
                                Users = t.Users.Where(x => x.Age > 25).Select(user => new Models.UsersModel()
                                {
                                    Name = user.Name,
                                    UserId = user.UserId
                                })
                            });
```

With `HashSet<int>`, this operation `hash.Contains(x.Id)` is [O(1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `O(n)` with `listOfUserIds`

Comment: HashSet has no push method

Comment: Can you please clarify why x.Id within listOfUserIds.contains() ? Shouldn't it be user.UserId?

Comment: Doesn't work as `user` would not be accessible in the topmost `where`.

Comment: @shyamal parikh: Why? `x` is the same as `t` in your `Select`. I see  `t.Users` there. `x.Users.Any` should work

Comment: No! `x` is different from `t` as `t` inherits from model `Models.SomeModel` while `x` is database model

Comment: @shyamal parikh: Are you sure? I see `.Select(t => new Models.SomeModel() `. In this case, `t` is an item in your `some_table`

Comment: @KhanhTO Extremely confident they both are different models

Comment: @shyamal parikh: Did you check that it works or not? Try running the code. I'm sure they are the same.

Comment: Checked, x.Users is not valid

Comment: Ok I am very sorry! I have x.Users and t.something_Users... so they didn't match